# Get a .p7b file from a .jks file

Tags: single-sign-on, x509certificate, saml, jks, p7b

I have a .Net SAML implementation that verifies assertions' signatures against a [PKCS 7 certificate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315) in a `.p7b` file.

I have a customer who have a Java based identity provider. They can only provide their certificate in a [Java key store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystore) `.jks` file.

I can verify the assertions that their identity provider sends, but I can't check that those assertions were signed by a trusted provider without verifying them against the certificates in the Java key store.

I can find lots online on how to add a `.p7b` certificate to a `.jks` file, but nothing on how to reverse the process.

How do I get a `.p7b` certificate (that .Net and Windows can open) from a supplied `.jks` file?

Alternatively I'm loading the `.p7b` into .Net using the native [`X509Chain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation. If I can't convert the `.jks` is there any way to load it in .Net in a way that lets me check the assertions' signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a command line utility in Java that do what I need. In the Java runtime directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin` on my machine) there is a utility called [`keytool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) (my newlines for readability):

```
>keytool -importkeystore 
         -srckeystore clientStore.jks -srcstoretype JKS 
         -destkeystore outputStore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

This produces an output store called `outputStore.p12` that I can load in .Net with `X509Certificate2Collection.Import()`